# Can an example of a non-measurable set be exhibited with non-well-founded set theories?

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets) it says an example of a non-measurable set cannot be exhibited, although they do exist.

I was curious what premises lead to this conclusion, and whether there are ways to exhibit non-measurable sets, for example with less conventional axioms such as [anti foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom).

> In non-well-founded set theory, sets can **EXIST** not found in well-founded set theory.  But can it also **EXHIBIT** some well-founded sets which *are* found in well-founded set theory but cannot be *exhibited* in well-founded theories?

Comment: Anti-foundation won't help you here, since every subset of $\mathbb R$ is in **WF** anyway, as is the entire Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Sorry @HenningMakholm I'm being a bit slow here.  Are you saying many unmeasurable sets are well-founded, so anti-foundation contributes nothing to help?

Comment: You will find the Wikipedia [non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set) entry of interest.

Comment: Thanks @Somos My difficulty at the moment is determining whether the set on which $F$ acts is actually a set at all or whether it contains itself, which it appears it may do. Then I feel like I've lost before I even start studying that material as it all depends on standard set theory. 

Comment: @samerivertwice: I'm saying _every_ non-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ is well-founded (in the set-theoretic sense), simply by virtue of being a subset of $\mathbb R$ in the first place.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks.  I think you're pointing out that the very concept of "non-measurable" is predicated upon well-founded set theory and therefore its definition would need to first be extended.  Is that right?

Comment: @samerivertwice: No, I'm pointing out that there is no connection at all between measurability (or lack of same) and well-foundedness, because _even if there are_ non-well-founded-sets, **all real numbers and all sets of real numbers** will be among those sets that happen to be well-founded. This is not about measurability at all -- merely about what the real numbers _are_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm i struggle with your comment because it seems to address the matter of the *existence* of non-measurable sets in **WF** rather than address what capacity a system stronger than **WF** has to *exhibit* a set which is in **WF** but which **WF** lacks the capacity to exhibit. I'm trying to understand what more is required to *exhibit* a non-measurable set. Is your comment is already notwithstanding this?

Comment: @samerivertwice: I don't know how else to say it. _Well-foundedness is completely irrelevant for the existence of non-measurable sets_. If you have a set theory without Foundation, all subsets of $\mathbb R$ in that theory will be in **WF**, and each of them is measurable in the larger model if and only if they are measurable as seen within **WF**. Speaking about well-foundedness in the context of which sets are measurable is barking up an entirely wrong tree.

Comment: It's like asking how early you need to arrive at the airport to minimize the risk that your flight will delayed by bad weather.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm really sorry. I say these sets exist in *WF* but can't be exhibited and you seem to answer by pointing out they exist in *WF*, which I have already taken as a premise. If you said not-wf has no greater power to exhibit wf-sets this would maybe make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from the ambiguity of "exhibit," so let me first try to pin that down.

Under reasonable hypotheses there is a model $M$ of ZFC such that:

- $M$ thinks there is a non-measurable set of reals (this is for free, since $M$ satisfies ZFC), but
- Every parameter-freely definable set of reals in $M$ is measurable - more precisely, for each formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of set theory such that $M$ thinks there is exactly one set of reals satisfying $\varphi$, we have that $M$ thinks that that set is measurable.

In particular, under these reasonable hypotheses there is no formula $\varphi$ such that ZFC proves "$\varphi$ defines a unique set of reals and that set is non-measurable." Moreover, by upgrading those hypotheses we can make $M$ a model of any large cardinal axiom I'm aware of.

---

Now what about a theory of the form ZFC$^-$ + $A$, where $A$ is some antifoundation axiom (e.g. Aczel's $AFA$)?

The answer, in every instance I'm aware of, is that **nothing changes** - and this is a consequence of the definability arguments we use to establish the consistency of such a theory.

Specifically, in every case I'm aware of we prove the consistency of ZFC$^-$ + $A$ relative to that of ZFC (perhaps plus some large cardinaly hypothesis $*$) by showing how any model $N$ of ZFC (+ $*$) "definably interprets" a model $N'$ of ZFC$^-$ + $A$, and we get for free (looking at this interpretation) that $WF(N')$ (= the well-founded part of $N'$) is isomorphic to $N$ definably in $N$. The result is that any parameter-freely-definable-in-$N'$ subset of $WF(N')$ is already parameter-freely definable in $WF(N')$ - and since measurability is calculated in the well-founded part, putting all this together we get that a parameter-freely-definable non-measurable set in $N'$ yields (indeed, "is") a parameter-freely definable non-measurable set in $N$.